# How does a trackball reduce pain caused by RSI?

Tags: trackball

I developed RSI ([Repetitive Strain Injury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetitive_strain_injury)) in my index fingers due excessive mouse clicking. I might consider a trackball as many people suggested.

But how does trackball help? I can see it get 2 buttons and a ball which require some fingers to operate on. Will I RSI while I click on the buttons with other healthy fingers?

Logitech TrackMan Wheel:

[image]

I highly doubt this trackball, I assume we are still using the index and middle finger for clicking.

Logitech Marble Mouse:

[image]

I think we will use the thumb to click the left button, will I develop RSI on my thumb? And the right button, which finger should I use?

If you know other trackball which might help, please tell me which is the design that help to avoid the stress.

Comment: Seems switching mice types and hands every hour or so is the best way to mitigate RSI, I don't think there is a one type fixit for that condition.

Comment: I would definitely **ask a professional** for medical advice instead of an online community. That being said, I can't see why clicking on a trackball would be better or worse than clicking with a mouse -- as @Moab said, maybe a more frequent switching will help.

Comment: I visited a practitioner, he said only REST can heal this. I tried many method, it just don't cure.

Comment: If it's RSI in your fingers and not your wrist, and it's caused by the mouse and not your keyboard, then a trackball alone won't help you.  You need a mouse or trackball that actually fits your hand and feels comfortable to use.

Comment: RSI can affect anything from a finger to your elbow or shoulder, it is a term related to a condition rather than a specific body part, since your issue is with your fingers, I doubt a trackball will change anything, switching hands may help relieve it somewhat.

Comment: as @slhck mentioned, please visit certified medical professional. Visit another physician to get a second opinion. This is not a right place to ask about health advice

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

1 - Quit mousing altogether. I now use a Kensington Expert Mouse Trackball and swap back and forth every couple of days.

2 - Touch type. If I start getting lazy and begin to hunt and peck, things start hurting.

Here's what didn't work:

1 - Foot pedals of any sort. They just move the pain from the hands to the lower back.

2 - Wacom Tablet. A whole new location for RSI to kick in! Joy!

3 - Continuing computer use at pre-RSI levels. When it's all said and done, you're gonna have to change your computer habits. If you can't quit playing WoW altogether, you'll have to at least cut down drastically.

Comment: wow, I once wanted to buy a wacom tablet! Didn't work?!

Comment: It did for a time, but all it does is move RSI to a new location

Comment: So, how is the Kensington Expert Mouse Trackball? Have tried the other trackball by logitech?

Comment: where is the new location of RSI?

Comment: Its great, the best idea would be to get 3 forms of input and simply switch on a rota, this will keep you using all the joints etc

Comment: Unless you're an artist or aspiring to be one, it makes no sense to buy a Wacom tablet (or any tablet input device).